# asyncio Error: ValueError parameters must be provided

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/finetuning/cross_encoder_finetuning/cross_encoder_finetuning/

I'm trying this code in macOS env.
How can I run this async function?

Error:

```
 line 252, in aevaluate
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: query, response, second_response, and reference must be provided
```

`await evaluator_gpt4_pairwise.aevaluate` function could be the key,

but I don't know how can I fix it to right code.
Here is the code.

Code:

```
async def baseline_evaluate(df_test : pd.DataFrame):
    os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-.."
    openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
    gpt4 = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4")
    evaluator_gpt4_pairwise = PairwiseComparisonEvaluator(llm=gpt4)
    pairwise_scores_list = []
    no_reranker_dict_list = []

    # Iterate over the rows of the dataset
    for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
        documents = [Document(text=row["paper"])]
        query_list = row["questions"]
        reference_answers_list = row["answers"]
        number_of_accepted_queries = 0
        print("Index: ",index)
        print(len(documents),len(query_list),len(reference_answers_list))

        # Create vector index for the current row being iterated
        vector_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
        # Query the vector index with a top_k value of top 3 documents without any reranker
        query_engine = vector_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=3)
        assert len(query_list) == len(reference_answers_list)
        pairwise_local_score = 0

        for index in range(0, len(query_list)):
            query = query_list[index]
            reference = reference_answers_list[index]

            if reference != "Unacceptable":
                number_of_accepted_queries += 1

                response = str(query_engine.query(query))

                no_reranker_dict = {
                    "query": query,
                    "response": response,
                    "reference": reference,
                }
                no_reranker_dict_list.append(no_reranker_dict)

                # Compare the generated answers with the reference answers of the respective sample using
                # Pairwise Comparison Evaluator and add the scores to a list

                pairwise_eval_result = await evaluator_gpt4_pairwise.aevaluate(
                    query, response=response, reference=reference
                )
                print(pairwise_eval_result)

                pairwise_score = pairwise_eval_result.score

                pairwise_local_score += pairwise_score

            else:
                pass

        if number_of_accepted_queries > 0:
            avg_pairwise_local_score = (
                pairwise_local_score / number_of_accepted_queries
            )
            pairwise_scores_list.append(avg_pairwise_local_score)


    overal_pairwise_average_score = sum(pairwise_scores_list) / len(
        pairwise_scores_list
    )

    df_responses = pd.DataFrame(no_reranker_dict_list)
    df_responses.to_csv("No_Reranker_Responses.csv")
    results_dict = {
        "name": ["Without Reranker"],
        "pairwise score": [overal_pairwise_average_score],
    }
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_dict)
    print(results_df)



if __name__=="__main__":

    df_test = set_data()
    asyncio.run(baseline_evaluate(df_test))
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `second_response` is required as well…!?

Comment: @deceze Oooooh my God.. That was the point. I'm so surprised because I used the code in the official document haha :D Thank you in politely.